# New jenkins server after inital setup - blank screen

Tags: jenkins

I have a fairly new installation of Jenkins that was working prior to Christmas, but today when I try to access it I get a blank browser screen. During the intial setup I successfully unlocked the server and verified that everything was working, but did not install any plugins as the server was firewalled. This has since been resolved.

Requests to http://server-name:8080/ return a blank screen, with the following source code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><head resURL="/static/9fe70b8e" data-rooturl="" data-resurl="/static/9fe70b8e">
        
    <title>Jenkins [Jenkins]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/9fe70b8e/css/layout-common.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/9fe70b8e/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/9fe70b8e/css/color.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/9fe70b8e/css/responsive-grid.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/9fe70b8e/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
    <link color="black" rel="mask-icon" href="/images/mask-icon.svg" />
    <script>var isRunAsTest=false; var rootURL=""; var resURL="/static/9fe70b8e";</script>
    <script src="/static/9fe70b8e/scripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/9fe70b8e/scripts/behavior.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='/adjuncts/9fe70b8e/org/kohsuke/stapler/bind.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

The latest entry in the jenkins.log file has the following:

2021-01-06 07:59:38.063+0000 [id=15]    WARNING o.e.jetty.server.HttpChannel#handleException: ERROR dispatch failed
org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.190.3.jar!/lib/layout/view.jelly:42:20: <d:invokeBody> class hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer is missing its descriptor

I've tried restarting the server and this didn't change anything. Can anybody provide some pointers (or if this is the wrong place to raise something like this, let me know where I should ask!)

Cheers,

Brendan